# Trying to create dynamic array, giving unexpected results

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I've begun trying to experiment with C and I've created code describing a vector:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define RESIZE_CONSTANT 2

typedef struct
{
    char* contents;
    int length;
} V_Element;

typedef struct 
{
    V_Element* ElementList;
    int pos;
    int size;
} Vector;

Vector newVec(int size)
{
    Vector vec;
    vec.ElementList = malloc(size * sizeof(V_Element));
    vec.pos = 0;
    vec.size = size;

    if(vec.ElementList == NULL)
    {
        //Error
    }

    else
    {
        return vec;
    }
}

void reSize(Vector *vec)
{
    int newsize = vec->size * RESIZE_CONSTANT;
    vec->ElementList = realloc(vec->ElementList,  newsize * sizeof(V_Element));

    if(vec->ElementList != NULL)
    {
        vec->size = newsize;
    }
}

void push_back(Vector *vec, V_Element element)
{
    if(vec->size > vec->pos)
    {
        vec->pos++;
        vec->ElementList[vec->pos] = element;
    }

    if(vec->size <= vec->pos)
    {
        reSize(vec);
        push_back(vec, element);
    }   
}

V_Element* at(Vector *vec, int pos)
{
    if(pos > vec->size || pos > vec->pos)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    else{
        return &vec->ElementList[pos];
    }
}

void delVector(Vector vec)
{
    free(vec.ElementList);
}
```

it has function for retrieving pushing back and allocating a vector, which is simply an array of V_Elements.

and main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Vector.h"


int main()
{
    char input[2000];

    scanf("%s", &input);    

    V_Element a;
    a.contents = input;
    a.length = strlen(input);

    Vector test = newVec(5);
    push_back(&test, a);
    printf("%s", (at(&test, 0))->contents);
    delVector(test);

}
```

This code seems to be giving me undefined behavior though, is there something i missed? thank you

Comment: it looks like you pushed your element onto your vector at position 1 because of this code: `vec->pos++;
 vec->ElementList[vec->pos] = element;` but you attempt to fetch a value at position 0

Comment: Ah you're right, incrementing the position after gives the wanted effect thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the issue you were originally seeing (and correctly answered by Vinbot), you need to think about your test code in main, particularly this section:

```
V_Element a;
a.contents = input;
a.length = strlen(input);
```

Remember that you are not copying the string, but rather copying the pointer value, this means that if you were to change the content of input (say by another scanf), then you would also change the value of the string in the first element of your vector.  For example consider this modification to your main:

```
int main()
{
    char input[2000];
    int   ndx;

    Vector   test = newVec(5);

    for(ndx = 0; ndx < 5; ndx++)
    {
       V_Element* pTemp = malloc(sizeof(V_Element));

       printf("enter %d string: ", ndx);
       fgets(input, 1999, stdin);

       pTemp->contents = input;
       pTemp->length = strlen(input);

       push_back(&test, *pTemp);
    }

    for(ndx = 0; ndx < 5; ndx++)
    {
        printf("(length: %d) %s", at(&test,ndx)->length, (at(&test, ndx))->contents);
    }
}
```

A sample run gives :

```
    [******@broadsword junk]$ ./vecTest
    enter 0 string: foo
    enter 1 string: bar
    enter 2 string: baz
    enter 3 string: foobar
    enter 4 string: foobarbaz
    (length: 4) foobarbaz
    (length: 4) foobarbaz
    (length: 4) foobarbaz
    (length: 7) foobarbaz
    (length: 10) foobarbaz
```

You should think about what is happening, and how to fix it.  hint: this is an example of shallow copy versus deep copy (you normally hear this in terms of C++, it is applicable here).

Comment: Would I have to use a strdup(input) to deep copy the contents?

Comment: Changing my code to a.contents = strdup(input) does not seem to fix the problem, should I be using strcpy() instead? Thanks! @thurizas

Comment: @qwesr - I would do two things, first you need to allocate memory for the new string ,something alone the lines of a.contents = malloc(strlen(input)+1), and then copy the input into the newly allocated memory.  Doing this, you will need to rework you cleanup code to insure that you delete all the memory.  Also, it might be worthwhile to set the contents member to NULL when a new node is created.         Finally, my code example does have a number of memory leaks in it..I knowingly left them in hopes of keeping the code short and understandable.